# How to filter out duplicate objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, typescript, object

I have an array full of triangles. Triangles are composed of 3 Point objects (x and y coordinates). Some triangles are composed of the same points but in different order with previous as seen from the pictures. How can I filter out these duplicates? 
NOTE: I supplied the code which is not working below.

[image]

[image]

```
     let cleanedTriangles = [];

     for (let i = 0; i < triangles.length; i++)
     {
        if (i = 0)
        {
            cleanedTriangles.push(triangles[i])
        }
        else
        {
            for (let j = 0; j < cleanedTriangles.length; j++)
            {
              if (
                 !((triangles[i].p1.x === cleanedTriangles[j].p1.x || triangles[i].p1.x === cleanedTriangles[j].p2.x || triangles[i].p1.x === cleanedTriangles[j].p3.x)
                     &&
                     (triangles[i].p2.x === cleanedTriangles[j].p1.x || triangles[i].p2.x === cleanedTriangles[j].p2.x || triangles[i].p2.x === cleanedTriangles[j].p3.x)
                     &&
                     (triangles[i].p3.x === cleanedTriangles[j].p1.x || triangles[i].p3.x === cleanedTriangles[j].p2.x || triangles[i].p3.x === cleanedTriangles[j].p3.x)
                     &&
                     (triangles[i].p1.y === cleanedTriangles[j].p1.y || triangles[i].p1.y === cleanedTriangles[j].p2.y || triangles[i].p1.y === cleanedTriangles[j].p3.y)
                     &&
                     (triangles[i].p2.y === cleanedTriangles[j].p1.y || triangles[i].p2.y === cleanedTriangles[j].p2.y || triangles[i].p2.y === cleanedTriangles[j].p3.y)
                     &&
                     (triangles[i].p3.y === cleanedTriangles[j].p1.y || triangles[i].p3.y === cleanedTriangles[j].p2.y || triangles[i].p3.y === cleanedTriangles[j].p3.y)
                 )
              )
              {
                 cleanedTriangles.push(triangles[i])
              }
            }

        }
     }


function Point(x, y)
{

    this.x = x || 0;    

    this.y = y || 0;

}


function Triangle(point1, point2, point3)
{
    this.p1 = point1 || new Point(0, 0);    

    this.p2 = point2 || new Point(0, 0);

    this.p3 = point3 || new Point(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Instead of your console logs add your original input and expected output.

Comment: you should add your code to question instead of screenshot

Comment: have same points the same `id`?

Comment: @NinaScholz no it can be different. The only same things are x and y coordinates.

Comment: @HienNguyen I added code of what I tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the points in an array, sort by `x` and `y` ascending, create a string out of the coordinates and take this as key for a `Set`. Then filter.

```js
var array = [{ p1: { x: 1, y: 1 }, p2: { x: 3, y: 1 }, p3: { x: 1, y: 4 } }, { p1: { x: 1, y: 1 }, p2: { x: 3, y: 1 }, p3: { x: 1, y: 4 } }, { p1: { x: 1, y: 1 }, p2: { x: 1, y: 4 }, p3: { x: 3, y: 1 } }, { p1: { x: 1, y: 1 }, p2: { x: 3, y: 1 }, p3: { x: 1, y: 4 } }, { p1: { x: 1, y: 1 }, p2: { x: 2, y: 7 }, p3: { x: 1, y: 4 } }, { p1: { x: 2, y: 5 }, p2: { x: 3, y: 1 }, p3: { x: 1, y: 4 } }],
    triangles = new Set,
    result = array.filter(({ p1, p2, p3 }) => {
        var key = JSON.stringify([p1, p2, p3].sort((a, b) => a.x - b.x || a.y - b.y));
        return !triangles.has(key) && triangles.add(key);
    });

console.log(result);
console.log([...triangles]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thank you so much for this concise and neat answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do a very logical approach: calculate the circumference of the triangles. If two triangles don't have the same perimeter, then they cannot be identical, therefore their vertexes (or peaks? or whatever in English ;) ) cannot be the same.

```js
const triangleArray = [{
    p1: {
      x: 10,
      y: 5
    },
    p2: {
      x: 11,
      y: 5
    },
    p3: {
      x: 10,
      y: 2
    }
  },
  {
    p1: {
      x: 8,
      y: 4
    },
    p2: {
      x: 7,
      y: 5
    },
    p3: {
      x: 10,
      y: 2
    }
  },
  {
    p1: {
      x: 10,
      y: 5
    },
    p2: {
      x: 11,
      y: 5
    },
    p3: {
      x: 10,
      y: 2
    }
  }
]


triangleArray.forEach(triangle => {
  triangle.perimeter = calcPerimeter(triangle.p1, triangle.p2, triangle.p3)
})

console.log(triangleArray)

// Math.hypot() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot
function calcSideLength(p1, p2) {
  return Math.hypot(p1.x - p2.x, p1.y - p2.y)
}

function calcPerimeter(p1, p2, p3) {
  return calcSideLength(p1, p2) + calcSideLength(p2, p3) + calcSideLength(p3, p1)
}
```

Then I would check those triangles that have the same perimeter if they have the same endpoints